# UnknownError when getting file from OneDrive Graph API

Tags: onedrive, microsoft-graph-api

I'm getting an "UnknownError" code back from the Graph API when trying to retrieve a file from OneDrive.

E.g. if I log in to the Graph Explorer, sign in to my tenant, and then try:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/V1.0/groups/56372565-7632-4676-9224-f5266938fb04/drive/root:/sageData/_groupMetadata.json/content
```

I get the following response:

```
Status Code: 404

{
    "error": {
        "code": "UnknownError",
        "message": "",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "3ddca056-e579-4b94-9410-bc18f6adb929",
            "date": "2017-01-25T10:56:21"
        }
    }
}
```

This has persisted even after deleting and recreating the file, although this exact request has worked on occasion.

Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated Answer:
This issue should now be resolved.

Original Answer:
This unfortunately appears to be a bug - we'll work on getting it fixed ASAP!

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. I don't suppose you have a bug tracker, or an estimate on timescales for getting a fix?

Comment: Peter: I created an issue on our GitHub repo: https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues/508